# In Python-Is there a way to extract the data in the column upto a certian character?

Tags: python

Below is the dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDSDj.png)

How can I extract only one entry in the third column before the '|'(pipe).

Kindly help me with this,I am trying this on Python .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In order to reasonably answer this question, you would need to specify _where_ this data is (a file? a webpage?) and the format of that data.

Comment: is this a csv file?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

If it's a dataframe , use
df.Col.apply( lambda x: x.split('|')[0])